# What is the statistical difference between Bose-Einstein and classical indistinguishable particles?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

My question arose when i was doing this qeustion:

> Consider a system of two atoms, each having ony 3 quantum states
> of energies 0, E and 2E. The system is in contact with a heat reservoir at
> temperature T. Write down the partition function Z for the system if the
> particles obey: a) Classical statistics and are indistinguishable, b) Bose Einstein Statistics

Now, i can't understand why both partition function aren't equal! I mean, the possible combinations are

$$\left ( 0,0 \right )\\ \left ( 0,1 \right )\\ \left ( 2,1 \right )\\ \left ( 1,1 \right )\\ \left ( 2,2 \right )\\ \left ( 2,0 \right)$$

For bose-einstein particles, and for classical distinguishable. Therefore

$$Z = 1 + e^{-\beta E} + 2e^{-\beta 2 E} + e^{-\beta 3 E} + e^{-\beta 4 E}$$

Now, i realize that i can't differentiate between both type of particles!
I mean, they both satisfy:

Particles "a" and "b" can be on the same state;

If we exchange "a" and "b", we got the same state.

Comment: Not sure how you are counting... For the classical distinguishable case there are 9 states. For identical bosons there are 6.

Comment: The partition function you wrote down is for identical bosons. For classical distinguishable particles, for example, the state "(0,1)" is different from the state "(1,0)."

Comment: @hft I have wrote it wrong... Sorry, the question ask for indistinguishable classical particles!

Comment: OK, then I think this question may be a duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294540/partition-function-for-classical-indistinguishable-particles-and-bose-particles

Comment: Ultimately the linked answer states that you treat "classical indistinguishable" particles by first working out the case for distinguishable particles and then dividing by the ad hoc "Gibbs factor" $N!$, which in this case is $2!=2$. So you would get $Z=(1+e^{-\beta E} + e^{-2\beta E})^2/2$

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "indistinguishable classical particles."

Comment: @Andrew I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "classical indistinguishable particles" presumably refers to treating the particles as distinguishable and then dividing the partition function by an overall factor of $N!$ - see e.g. the [Gibbs Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox).

However, this yields the wrong overcounting factor for (individual particle) states which are occupied by more than one particle.  For example, the two-particle state $(1,1)$ is only counted once even when the particles are considered distinguishable, so it should not be divided by $2$. Counting more carefully yields quantum statistics.